# C++ outputting wrong string

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

char FirstName[50];

char LastName[50];

char MyFirstName[5] = "Bill";

char MyLastName[10] =  "Dillinger";

cout << "Enter your first name" << endl;

cin >> FirstName;

cout << "Enter your last name" << endl;

cin >> LastName;

if (FirstName && LastName) {

cout << "Hello " << FirstName << " " << LastName << endl;

} else if(FirstName == MyFirstName && LastName == MyLastName) {

cout << "Hello, my creator!" << endl;

};


system("pause");

return 0;

}
```

Using the code above, I always get the first result from the if statement. I never get "Hello, my creator!" even if i input my name. How do I fix this code?

Comment: This is because `FirstName` and `LastName` can never be `false`. They will *always* point to something. You're using C++, so **use C++**. Drop your character arrays and use `std::string`.

Comment: I have to solve this problem using c-strings only

Comment: Not to mention that `FirstName` *NEVER* equals `MyFirstName`.  The compiler converts them to pointers, which cannot be the same.

Comment: If you MUST use character arrays then you can't use == because it compares the pointers to the arrays - you should use strcmp() to compare character arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through this.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
```

Fine so far, but a brief interlude here:  *please* invest time in indenting your code correctly.  It will make maintenance so much easier.  You'll thank me later.

In C++, you don't need to use C-style strings.  But you said you have to, which makes me wonder why your instructor didn't have you use C.  But anyway.

```
    char FirstName[50];
    char LastName[50];
    char *MyFirstName = "Bill";
    char *MyLastName =  "Dillinger";
```

Carrying on:

```
    cout << "Enter your first name" << endl;
    cin >> FirstName;

    cout << "Enter your last name" << endl;
    cin >> LastName;
```

Good so far, but with your `if` statement, we run into an issue..  Basically, in your old code, FirstName and LastName were *pointers* to a chunk of RAM that's allocated for you.  It's always allocated, because you did it on the stack.  (That is, you didn't use `new` and `delete`.)  Those pointers wouldn't ever be `NULL`, so your comparison will always be true!  Also, in my version, I'm using a standard C function called `strcmp` to compare the strings *pointed to* by the pointers.  *This is an important but subtle point.*  `LastName`, `MyFirstName`, et. al. are all pointers to the chunks of RAM you reserved with the `[50]` syntax above.  If you compare them directly, you're comparing two numbers.

So, I'll change your `if` blocks, because the second test (for equality) is definitely meaningful.

```
    if(strcmp(FirstName, MyFirstName) == 0 && strcmp(LastName, MyLastName) == 0) {
```

`strcmp` returns `0` if the two strings are equal.

```
        cout << "Hello, my creator!" << endl;
    }
    else {
         cout << "Hello " << FirstName << " " << LastName << endl;
    }
```

And we're home free!  Note that the following `system("pause")` command will work fine for you, as you're on Windows.  Just remember that it isn't portable to other platforms like Linux.

```
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: While you were composing this excellent answer, the OP commented that he must use C strings. @user2908414, in the real world, follow thirtythreeforty's advice. For your assignment, please take a look at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: Edited.  If OP later wants to use `std::string`, look back at my old answer at http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19532566/1.

Answer (score 0):

this makes no sense

```
if (FirstName && LastName)
```

the reason it does not make sense is that it is always true, FirsName and LastName are always != 0 since they are array addresses.

if you want to read arrays like that use `getline()`

```
std::cin.getline (FirstName,sizeof(FirstName));
```

Now when you have arrays it makes no sense comparing them as you do, the array names are addresses so comparing FirstName with MyFirstName will never be true

```
else if(FirstName == MyFirstName && LastName == MyLastName)
```

Instead you need to compare the *contents* of the arrays, this can be with `strcmp`

```
else if (!strcmp(FirstName,MyFirstName) && !strcmp(LastName,MyLastName))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first IF statement will always be true so the second one will never be executed.
Hence remove the 'else' from that statement.
The program should work right.

```
if(strcmp(FirstName,MyFirstName) && strcmp(LastName,MyLastName))
{
    cout << "Hello, my creator!" << endl;
};
```

Just a tip. Its always better to use pointers!